# Overlay Slide out menu

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a slide out menu which slides out from the right but the issue is that it Pushes the rest of the content to the side and I don't want that.

I want it to overlay the site content so the user can still see the content. Heres my code:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="navigation">
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger"></label>
// Site content
<div class="site-wrap"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navigation {
/* critical sizing and position styles */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;

/* non-critical appearance styles */
list-style: none;
background: #f8f8f8;
}

/* Navigation Menu - List items */
.nav-item {
/* non-critical appearance styles */
width: 200px;
float: right;
border-top: 1px solid #111;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.nav-item a {
/* non-critical appearance styles */
display: block;
padding: 1em;
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
color: white;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
color: #c74438;
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(75,20,20,0.65) 100%);
 }

/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
/* Critical position and size styles */
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 100%;
   left: 0;
   right: 500px;
   z-index: 1;

   /* non-critical apperance styles */

   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(254,255,255) 0%,rgb(221,241,249) 35%,rgb(160,216,239) 100%);
   background-size: 200%;
   }

/* Nav Trigger */
.nav-trigger {
/* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
/* critical positioning styles */
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right: 100px;
 z-index: 2;

/* non-critical apperance styles */
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
background-size: contain;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
 .nav-trigger + label {
  transition: 0.2s;
  }

 .nav-trigger:checked + label, .site-wrap {
   right: 415px;
  }

 .nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
     left: -300px;
     border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  }


 /* Micro reset */
   *,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
   html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;          }
```

Heres what it looks like now:

[image]

**Any help will be greatly appreciated!**

**Heres a working Coden Pen of the code above:**

http://codepen.io/coder26/pen/RaOGqZ

Comment: Hard to tell without working demo, but try setting different positions on the nav menu.

Comment: `Position: fixed;` should work like that: http://jsfiddle.net/9HQ4b/16/ , you doing sth wrong if your content is pushed. Check if you apply your styles.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#nav-trigger').click(function () {

        $('#content').css({'left':'0'});

    });


});
```

css

```
#content {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Here is the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rebWYM

jQuery is the cleanest solution as CSS alone won't do it. You'll need to append the content id to anything else you add into the site-wrap div.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `clear:left;` in `.site-wrap` class and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should bring you much closer to the desired solution. I set up a proper definition of the `.navigation` class and modified `.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap`

Please do not forget to move the content in the html part into the `.site-wrap` div.

```
.navigation {
    /* critical sizing and position styles */

    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /*left: 0;*/

    z-index: 0;
    /* non-critical appearance styles */

    list-style: none;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
/* Navigation Menu - List items */

.nav-item {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */

    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav-item a {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */

    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}
.nav-item a:hover {
    color: #c74438;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(75, 20, 20, 0.65) 100%);
}
/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */

.site-wrap {
    /* Critical position and size styles */

    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */

    clear: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    /* non-critical apperance styles */

    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(254, 255, 255) 0%, rgb(221, 241, 249) 35%, rgb(160, 216, 239) 100%);
    background-size: 200%;
}
/* Nav Trigger */

.nav-trigger {
    /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */

    position: fixed;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    /* critical positioning styles */

    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    /* non-critical apperance styles */

    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' x='0px' y='0px' width='30px' height='30px' viewBox='0 0 30 30' enable-background='new 0 0 30 30' xml:space='preserve'><rect width='30' height='6'/><rect y='24' width='30' height='6'/><rect y='12' width='30' height='6'/></svg>");
    background-size: contain;
}
/* Make the Magic Happen */

.nav-trigger + label {
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.nav-trigger:checked + label,
.sitewrap {
    right: 415px;
}
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
    /*left: -300px;*/

    position: fixed;
    border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    z-index: -333;
}
/* Micro reset */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```